# Where to insert <img> in HTML to create a background image in CSS (not CSS3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a codeacademy project called Broadway. I've been asked to place a background image in the page. Easy. 
The first method, and the easiest, 
is just to use this:

background: url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/broadway/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
background-size: cover

The CSS3 background-size property is a godsend.

However, I'm trying to figure out how to do this in CSS without the background and background-size properties.

I need to insert the above image into this HTML.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">  
    <div class="main">
      <h1>We are Broadway</h1>  
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My problem is no matter which div I put the image in, it always pushes the other
elements around (which makes sense to me.). I need the image to fit behind the phrase "We Are Broadway". Long story short, where do I insert the img element to get that, and what corresponding changes do I need in my style sheet?

For reference, here is what the site should look like:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/broadway/index.html

Comment: Since this is for a course, you must have recently learned the things you'll need to use. What have you learned so far / recently in the course?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add a background image using `<img/>` tag.

Only with CSS, inline (with the `style` attribute) or not.

Comment: I should have added this. There are two CSS only techniques listed (after the CSS3 technique) on this page that seem to indicate that someone placed an img element in HTML.